# sqlite3.DatabaseError: malformed database schema (?)

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I executed the python file in the first try & it worked. But when I included the code "IF NOT EXISTS" in the line `cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store (item TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL)")`& `cur.execute("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('Wine Glass,8,10.5')")` I am getting an error.

here is my code:

```
import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store (item TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('Wine Glass,8,10.5')")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

here is the error:

```
PS D:\mysite\Interacting with Databases> python 1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\mysite\Interacting with Databases\1.py", line 5, in <module>
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store (item TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL)")
sqlite3.DatabaseError: malformed database schema (?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the code:

`cur.execute("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('Wine Glass,8,10.5')")`

You are providing only single value to three-column table. Replace it with:

`cur.execute("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('Wine Glass','8','10.5')")`

and your code should work fine.